# Group by hour, aggregate average

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains job history:

```
CREATE TABLE jobHistory
(
   jobid int4,
   starttime timestamptz,
   endtime timestamptz
);
```

I'm trying to create an SQL query to show, for each hour, the average number of running jobs. There should be 24 rows (0-23 for 24 hours), to contain the average number of jobs running that hour.

The total number of rows in my `jobHistory` table is around 20k. Here's a sample:

```
jobid  startTime                 endTime
------------------------------------------------------
377    2017-11-02 15:43:43.0     2017-11-02 15:49:22.0
114    2017-11-02 15:47:05.0     2017-11-02 15:56:19.0
378    2017-11-02 15:49:22.0     2017-11-02 15:53:01.0
379    2017-11-02 15:53:01.0     2017-11-02 16:33:16.0
380    2017-11-02 16:33:16.0     2017-11-02 16:51:26.0
381    2017-11-02 16:51:26.0     2017-11-02 17:03:00.0
382    2017-11-02 17:03:00.0     2017-11-02 17:11:59.0
383    2017-11-02 17:11:59.0     2017-11-02 17:12:44.0
384    2017-11-02 17:12:43.0     2017-11-02 17:13:36.0
385    2017-11-02 17:13:36.0     2017-11-02 17:14:20.0
386    2017-11-02 17:14:20.0     2017-11-02 17:15:08.0
387    2017-11-02 17:15:08.0     2017-11-02 17:16:03.0
388    2017-11-02 17:16:03.0     2017-11-02 18:31:01.0
150    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 18:16:32.0
153    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 18:15:28.0
135    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 17:55:01.0
132    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 18:13:00.0
156    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 17:55:06.0
147    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 17:57:47.0
138    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 18:12:33.0
140    2017-11-02 17:55:00.0     2017-11-02 17:55:17.0
389    2017-11-02 18:31:01.0     2017-11-02 18:38:11.0
390    2017-11-02 18:38:11.0     2017-11-02 18:38:35.0
391    2017-11-02 18:38:35.0     2017-11-02 18:38:39.0
```

I'm looking for average number of jobs per hour. Jobs are running 24 hours a day, all day. Some hours have more jobs running than others. There's about 120 jobs total. Some take minutes, others several hours. To keep the load balanced, when I schedule a new job, I'd like to see which hour has least number of jobs on average.

Comment: Do you need to consider `start time` or `end time`? as in some cases they are different. And what do you mean by `average number of jobs running for that hour`? Shouldn't it be `total number of jobs running for that hour`? If  not, what's your logic for `average jobs`?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear.

I am assuming that you are looking for `total number of running jobs per hour` on the basis of column `starttime`, so below is the query.

```
SELECT count(jobid) AS TotalJobs,
       date_trunc('hour', starttime) AS Date_Hour
FROM jobHistory
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', starttime)
order by Date_Hour;
```

If you need it on the basis of `endTime`, you can change the above query replacing `starttime` with `endTime`

**Result:**

```
totaljobs   date_hour
-------------------------------
4           02.11.2017 15:00:00
2           02.11.2017 16:00:00
15          02.11.2017 17:00:00
3           02.11.2017 18:00:00
```

Hope this will help

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/CGPG81439)**

Comment: this is great zarruq, however you SQL is producing a row for each hour of each day. the result I'm looking for would only have 12 rows in the output, 1 for each hour of the day.  the first column would be the hour (0-23) and the second column in the result would be the average number of jobs running during that hour. this means the starttime and endtime would need to be considered to determine if a job were "running" during each hour. the "average" number of jobs would be the total count of jobs running divided by the total number of rows for each hour in the source set.

Comment: @aswift: still your query is not clear. Kindly add desired output result based on the sample data to your question or in comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who took a look at this. I'm convinced there is a way to get the answer using pure SQL, but I just can't figure it out. To answer my question, I coded a perl script to get the results.

Here's how it works.

1.) Get the number of days between the earliest job record and the latest job record, this will be used to AVERAGE the number of jobs for each occurrence of each hour 0-23.
2.) For each job record, increment a counter for each hour of the day that the job was running. For example, if the job ran from 2pm - 6pm, the script will increment a counter for the 2,3,4,5 and 6 hours. If the job was longer than 23 hours, I increment the values of 0-23 just once. At this point, I have a result that has 2 columns. The first column is the hour (0-23) and the second column is the number occurrences of jobs that ran during that hour.
3.) My script then takes the number from step 2  above and divides it by the number of days to produce an average.

Because I've written a perl script to produce the result, I now know that the best time slot to schedule new jobs is at 11AM.

If anyone is interested in tackling the SQL, I'd be interested in seeing how it's done. For now, I'll just keep my perl script handy.

Here's a link to the full Job History Data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi66s0thh4sfp46/JobHistoryData.csv?dl=0

Here's the output of my perl script that calculates the average number of running jobs for each hour:

0 = 2.49
1 = 2.10
2 = 2.16
3 = 2.02
4 = 4.10
5 = 2.86
6 = 2.00
7 = 1.69
8 = 1.69
9 = 1.80
10 = 1.67
11 = 1.53
12 = 1.76
13 = 1.73
14 = 8.33
15 = 2.24
16 = 1.63
17 = 8.67
18 = 6.12
19 = 5.00
20 = 4.84
21 = 3.76
22 = 10.43
23 = 4.37